# How to use a 24 V output sensor (analog) on a microcontroller with 5 V maximum input

Tags: microcontroller, voltage

I am working on a project for my internship. Now the boss asked if I can use an analog sensor with 24 V on a microcontroller that has a maximum input of 5 V.

Does anyone know how I can convert the voltage to a lower it? I have a Lopy 4 + expansion board 3.0 or an ESP32, Raspberry Pi 4 or an Arduino.

For the sensors: there are 9 to 12 sensors to be installed. Specific datasheet I have yet to get.

Update: My boss said also that another microcontroller with one of the programming languages is also possible if it can take 24 V (analog) input. We already have an STG-650 Barth, but it does not contain one of the programming languages.

Comment: What do you think. Boss may be testing you so if you hadn't got us to help you what options would you consider?

Comment: You can use a 5V voltage regulator.

Comment: A couple of resistors should do the trick most times.

Comment: @MissMulan 5V voltage regulator would give her an fixed output of 5V.

Comment: Yes She wants a 5V output.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with voltage dividers. They are everywhere in electronic circuits.

Comment: 24V is probably the supply voltage of the sensor. The output voltage (or current) of the analog sensor is important. For example, if it's a 4~20mA transmitter or a 0-10V signal conditioner the answer will be a bit different.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy  voltage dividers are affected by loads.Also if there is noise the output voltage will vary which we don't want.Better use a voltage regulator.

Comment: @MissMulan I believe the point is to read a 24V measurement voltage output from a sensor with a device that can measure voltages up to 5V. And for that, you can't possibly use a voltage regulator.

Comment: @MissMulan The load provided by a microprocessor analog input pin is usually both constant and small. If the resistors chosen are smaller than the load resistance, the error will be small as well. If greater accuracy is required, an op-amp voltage follower can be placed between the voltage divider and the input pin.

Comment: Zino - Hi, Please [edit] your question and add a link to the datasheet for your specific sensor. The details in that datasheet will help to confirm a likely misunderstanding in the comments above. Thanks.

Comment: @MissMulan - Hi, Unfortunately you have started a significant topic in these comments because you gave a (short) *answer* in the comments, instead of writing an answer. It says in the comments box, before you enter any text: "*Avoid answering questions in comments*". Please follow that advice in future. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing called "24V analog sensor" so what have you got there in reality? I would bet something supplied with 24V that gives out 4-20mA or 0-10V.

Answer (score 1):

#### If your sensor output is an analog signal...

You could use a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) to bring down the voltage on the range of 0-5V maximum, and then a [voltage follower (using an op-amp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier)) (check Figure 3 is your schematic, really simple). You use voltage follower to not drain any current from the voltage divider, this will mess up the voltage divider circuit.

Then, your 24V will be your 5V (this is your calibration,) your 12V will be 2.5V, and 0V will be 0V.

If you need more accuracy, you can always [use an ADC](https://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine?N=7283644) (analog to digital converter) that takes your 24V and gives a 12-bit output (or 8-bit, depends on the ADC accuracy,) usually to I2C line (so you will need to communicate with your ADC with I2C.)

#### If your sensor output is a digital signal...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foIlst.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value of R1 depends on the optocoupler specifications. The optocoupler is an LED (on the side of the 24V). If the datasheet says 0.1A maximum current to the LED, you do:

```
I = V / R
R = 24V / 0.1 
R  = 240 Ohms
```

Comment: The sensor is analog. Your solution is for a digital input. It might be best to give the OP a hint rather than an answer. S/he will learn more working it out.

Comment: This is overkill in any event.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy hmm I always use one of these two options on my circuits. What would be a better one?

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios a voltage divider, or a voltage divider followed by an op-amp voltage follower. Saw your optocoupler circuit, but didn't see your edit saying to use voltage divider w/ or w/o voltage follower.

Comment: If it's 24V digital, then you would simply use a voltage divider, design for 30V, optionally add 10k in series to protect the MCU, add a TVS if you have reason to fear spikes or EMF. We end up with 3 resistors and a diode at most, it's not rocket science. No need for optocouplers.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Sorry, if you want more info: it is a project with 9 - 12 sensors. We where thinking about a voltage divider but then we have te be sure the voltage will stay the same over the whole line. My boss said if it is necessary, we can buy a microcontroller with 24V input and python, micropython, Arduino or another programming language. So if anyone has some reccommended controllers?

Comment: Just buy precision resistors (1% or better). And if you want really good accuracy, calibrate your sensors afterward using the readings you get on your microcontroller.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I would recommend deleting the first part of your answer which talks about optocouplers. This is a newbie question and it might cause confusion.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios -- I reformatted your answer and fixed some typos to address Drew's feedback for you. However, I would echo the concerns of others above that galvanic isolation (baring additional information from the OP) is not a requirement in this design -- ergo an optoisolator is unnecessary. If you want to implement level conversion using transistors you can do that without the optical component.

Comment: One *could* use an optocoupler for analog if the driving signal is strong enough to drive the LED. The phototransistor current output would be proportional to the LED current input * (current transfer ratio). This could be characterized and compensated by software. Then you get galvanic isolation for your trouble.